# Are dice games suitable for discussion here? Eg Dudo / liar dice?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I regularly play Dudo (peruvian liar dice, maybe branded as "Perudo" in the US?) with friends, especially at the pub, (as with no stakes, it's allowed in a UK pub, and because dice are waterproof, the game can't get ruined).

Are dice games fair for discussion here? There aren't any cards or boards, but it's a social, strategic game, very much of the ilk discussed here. And it seems to me it would be better incorporated into this site, than any other Stack exchange site.

What about other predominately dice based games? Poker dice for instance? (which is a dice game *based* on a card game)

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, Perudo is the US-branded version of liar's dice.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**,

Simplified, our definition of a "boardgame" is

- Normally you play it while sitting at a table
- A computer is not necessary
- There are winning/losing conditions

Dice games fit those criteria.

Comment: Oh! I thought they were not allowed, and refrained from asking them. Shouldn't the title be clarified to "Human strategy games" or something like it (or is it too late)?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - if the site ever escapes beta there may be a name change involved, but not likely before then.