# Are casino games on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I see [this meta post](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317/are-dice-games-suitable-for-discussion-here-eg-dudo-liar-dice)

But does this make all casino style gaming on topic here? There is an Expert Casino Gaming and Gambling in Area 51, but it isn't gaining much traction.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Link fixed. Thanks @murgatroid99

Comment: OK, now I'm not exactly sure what you're asking about. That post says that dice games are on-topic. Card games are obviously on topic.

Comment: Sports betting, horse gambling, keno, roulette. Any of those.

Comment: @murgtroid99 Read the first sentence as *"I see this meta post and it doesn't cover the topic I want to ask about as specifically as I would like so please don't confuse this as a duplicate question."* and the post makes a little more sense.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Rainbolt. That's exactly what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That question/answer specifically means that tabletop dice games on topic; what you're asking about is not just dice games. The full version of the criteria it mentioned for board/card/dice/tabletop games on topic here:

- Be playable on or around a table
- Have objective rules of play and win conditions
- Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
- Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

A game must meet *all* of these in order to be on topic.

Sports betting and horse gambling most certainly do not meet these criteria. It sounds like keno uses a computer, so it's also off topic.

Roulette... could I guess be on topic? It fits all the criteria. I don't think it sounds like a terribly *interesting* game - you're not making really meaningful decisions - but the criteria don't require that. See also [Are questions about “games” that require no decision-making acceptable?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/are-questions-about-games-that-require-no-decision-making-acceptable) - it's asking about games like Candyland, which we've decided are fine.

So in the end, a lot of the popular gambling games are on topic here - because they have a board/card/dice game component in addition to the fact that people wager money on them. But wagering money on something doesn't make it into a board game; gambling in general is not on topic here, and if you want to talk about that, you'll want to support that proposal you mention.

Comment: I agree that roulette isn't incredibly interesting. I guess the others could fall into the dynamic challenge aspect (randomization).

Comment: @BrianRobbins Edited to clarify a bit. The others may perhaps have a dynamic challenge, but they aren't playable by hand around a table. Roulette does seem to be on topic - I was pointing out that the main reason it seems like it might not be (not interesting) is not actually a criterion, so it's fine.