# Should a "Poker Dice" tag exist?

Tags: support, tagging

Recently, I posted a post about Poker Dice, but I had to resort to the combination [poker][dice]. Poker has **nothing** to do with this. Dice **barely** has anything to did with this. Therefore, I think that there should  be a new tag for questions regarding this game. Or does one already *technically* exist?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the game of Poker Dice is on-topic at all, then it is reasonable to have a tag for it.  After all, it is normal to have a tag for each game.

Dice games are on-topic, according to [this earlier discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/11571), so Poker Dice qualifies.

At your level of reputation, you can create a new tag.  So you could add it to your question and see how it is received.

Incidentally, the only other question I can see that references Poker Dice [(here)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/34561/11571) is tagged with just [dice](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice).

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and create the tag, that reasoning is perfectly solid.

If we do have a tag for this, it's not very discoverable to either of us. Were we to discover it later we'd probably create a synonym. We can cross that bridge when we come to it.